# How to push packages to client Mac OS X machines from OS X server at login of clients?

Tags: group-policy, login, mac-osx-server

I wanted to know if there is option to install application at login time in Mac OS X.That is, push packages to client Mac OS X machines from OS X server at login of clients similar to Group Policy objects of Windows server and the option "Install this application at logon".

Answer (score 1):

I believe Apple's [Remote Desktop 3](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/softwaredistribution.html) will do this for you. I don't think it has all the power of GPOs, but it does let you remotely schedule installs and restart computers.